# Report builder parameters not working

Tags: parameters, report

I have a report(report builder 3.0) running from a view in my 2008R2 SQL table.

I have 4 parameters already programmed and working that select their values from the existing data via a query.

"Select distinct FIELD from VIEW"

I have the default value set to all as well.

I have two more parameters that I want to use also.

When I add them in the same way.  when I do this, the report will run the first time with the default values selected, but if I try to run it again, even with the same parameters set, the report will deselect all choices for the parameter and not run the report.

If anything needs more clarification or images uploaded, please let me know.

Thank you in advance,

Steve Hathaway

I tried the report by not using the View and the full query.  No changes.  Here is the query for the main dataset with the parameters in place.

```
SELECT        
   dbo.Main.CallLogID, 
   dbo.Main.CallDateTime, 
   dbo.Main.DayofWeek, 
   dbo.Main.LOC, 
   dbo.Main.ManagingOffice, 
   Data_Shack.dbo.OptionsData.Fullname, 
   dbo.Source.Source, 
   dbo.NatureofCall.NatureOfCall,
   dbo.Response.Response, 
   dbo.Main.UserName, 
   dbo.Main.flagDeleted
FROM 
   dbo.Main LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.NatureofCall ON dbo.Main.NatureofCall = dbo.NatureofCall.NOCID LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.Response ON dbo.Main.Response = dbo.Response.ResponseID LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.Source ON dbo.Main.Source = dbo.Source.SourceID LEFT OUTER JOIN
   Data_Shack.dbo.OptionsData ON dbo.Main.ClientName = Data_Shack.dbo.OptionsData.ChildID
WHERE
   (Main.LOC IN (@LOC)) AND
   (Main.ManagingOffice IN (@ManagingOffice)) AND
   (Response.Response IN (@Response)) AND
   (Main.UserName IN (@UserName)) AND
   (source.source IN (@S)) AND
   (NatureofCall.NatureOfCall in (@NOC))
```

The first 4 parameters work fine.

Comment: Anybody got any ideas why the parameter won't work and keeps clearing out?

Answer (score 0):

Come to find out, the supporting tables for the Drop down menus, I had copied and pasted the text into from a customer supplied excel document.  The items had some sort of LF or CR embedded in it that came over in the table value.

SQL Management Studio could handle it fine and displayed all data correctly, but when Report builder tried to deal it, it tweeked out.

I found this when I viewed the data in SQL MS, copied and pasted it into excel(I was going to recreate the tables), then I did this the info did not line up right in the columns.

Anyway, it is fixed.